# how to view test automation sreenshots in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, screenshot

I followed these  instructios  to  add screenshots to my tests

https://developers.google.com/cloud-test-lab/test-screenshots
screenshots are taken and appear to  to my scard but I can't view  them  in android studio. There is no "eye" icon on my run toolbar do I need to add it from sowhere ?

My AS version is 2.1.1
 Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for the "eye" icon on the toolbar of your test results panel (which you can open/close with Alt+4)? This toolbar looks like [image: this].

Also, please make sure to select a test in the test results tree to enable the icon's action.